# Adding additional random parameter as an argument in pool.map function in python 3.4.7

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I want to use multiprocessing on a large dataset to find the product of two columns and filter the data set with a given parameter in the argument. I constructed a test set, but I have been unable to get multiprocessing to work on this set.

Firstly, I am trying to divide the data set in parallelize_dataframe function and then apply multiply function and filter functions in subset_col function. Later I am appending the complete dataset back in parallelize_dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Lock

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                'col2': ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'cc', 'cc', 'cc'],
                'col3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                'col4': [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]})



def subset_col(df, p):
    print("Working with number: " + str(p))
    df[col5] = df[col3]*df[col4]
    df= df[df['col1'] == p]


def parallelize_dataframe(df, p, func, n_cores=80):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, n_cores)
    pool = Pool(n_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split, p))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df


df3 = parallelize_dataframe(df,1,subset_col)
```

The result should be product of col3 and col4 with col1 filtered with a value. But I always get an error saying:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 4, in parallelize_dataframe
struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

However, if I remove the filter "p" from all the functions, it works totally fine. Can someone help me debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official docs of [multiprocessing.Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map), it "supports supports only one *iterable* argument". Hence you need to change the interface of `subset_col` to take a single argument instead. Additionally you had forgotten to make columns strings, resulting in name errors. To reduce the amount of computations, you should filter before multiplying. Then a value should be returned unless your function operates solely via side effects (I assume you do not want this since you concatenate the pool results).

```
def subset_col(pair):
    df, p = pair
    print("Working with number: " + str(p))
    df = df[df['col1'] == p].copy()
    df['col5'] = df['col3']
    return df
```

Next, we will need to fix how you called `pool.map` since it should take only 2 arguments based on what you are doing (the 3rd, final argument would be chunksize). Since you want the same `p` to be used for each process, we will zip together the `dfs` with a repeated value of `p` for each. Also, consider using a context manager to handle closing resources.

```
def parallelize_dataframe(df, p, func, n_cores=None):
    if n_cores is None:
        n_cores = os.cpu_count()

    dfs = np.array_split(df, n_cores)
    pairs = zip(dfs, itertools.repeat(p))
    with Pool(n_cores) as pool:
        result = pool.map(func, pairs)

    df = pd.concat(result)
    return df
```

This now properly returns the new dataframe. But I am definitely dubious about you having a machine with 80 cores. Consider implementing `n_cores=None` to let [Python dynamically figure out](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) how many cores are on your machine by using `os.cpu_count`

```
df3 = parallelize_dataframe(df, 1, subset_col)
```

As per your request for a `Pool.starmap` variant:

```
def subset_col(df, p):
    # remove unpacking line
    ...

def parallelize_dataframe(df, p, func, n_cores=None):
    ...
    # change `pool.map(...)` to `pool.starmap(...)`
    ...
```

However you should note that `Pool` doesn't offer an `imap` or `imap_unordered` alternatives for `starmap` which are both lazy evaluation versions that differ whether or not to preserve order or not.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I am using ec2 instance, m5.24xlage. So, I have about 96 cores to work with. The problem I face though is that the dataframe is so big, I have to find a way to multiprocess to reduce the implementation time as low as possible. Isn't starmap supposed to allow multiple iterable arguments. I use R quite a lot and am familiar with foreach and doParallel. Trying to discover similar functions with in python.

Comment: I have update the above post for `starmap` varaint. However for such a large dataset you may want to consider using other tools than Pandas like [Dask](https://dask.org/). It is designed to have a similar API to Pandas and is specialized for large computations.